# Tag Syn: Operating Systems

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Synonym request:

[operating-systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems) -> [operating-system](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/operating-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)